# How can I pass templateUrl information from its parent component?

Tags: angular, templates

I just started to learn angular2 and got this situation, having a dropdown all over the pages and it changes its contents everytime being called, but the structure is same(that's why i set these as one component) its not shot list so like to use templateUrl over template.

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <div class="group" *ngFor...>
  <h4 class="title" *ngIf...></h4>
  <ul> 
   <li *ngFor...> 
    <a></a> 
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to pass its templateUrl from parents or components who called it?
and very grateful that I have a some place to answer these questions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Note that I'm using the `template` property rather than `templateUrl` for the sake of simplicity here. You can just drop the child component's HTML into its own template file. The idea here is that you can use the child's selector in its parent and bind its parent's properties to it using input binding.*

You're going to want to drop the selector into the parent component and bind your parent's properties to the child component using input bindings.

#### Parent component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <my-dropdown [foos]="foos" [bar]="bar"></my-dropdown>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    foos: string[];
    bar: boolean;

}
```

#### Child component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-dropdown',
    template: `
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="group" *ngFor="let foo of foos">
                <h4 class="title" *ngIf="bar === true">
                    <ul> 
                        <li *ngFor="let foo of foos"> 
                            <a></a> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    @Input() foos: string[];
    @Input() bar: boolean;

}
```

More information on component interaction in the [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)

Answer (score 1):

```
//our Dropdown app component
import {Component, NgModule, EventEmitter, OnInit , Output, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-dropdown',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li *ngFor="let value of dropdownConfiguration" 
                (click)="selectedValue(value)">
                  {{value.name}}
           </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class DropdownComponent {
  @Input() dropdownConfiguration : any[];
  @Output() selectedDropDownValue:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
  }
  selectedValue(value:any){
    this.selectedDropDownValue.emit(value);
  }
}
```

You can use the custom-dropdown in your parent component as

```
 <custom-dropdown (selectedDropDownValue)="changedValue($event)"
             [dropdownConfiguration]="dropdownConfig"   >
```

And the component code look as

```
dropdownConfig:any=[];
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.dropdownConfig=[{
        id:1
        name:'a'
    },{
        id:2
        name:'b'
    },{
        id:3
        name:'c'
    },
    ]

  }
  changedValue(value){
    console.log(value);
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZotVj973qexxAGR8Ukf?p=preview)**